# MySQL + изображение

Tags: mysql, изображения

Какой тип данных выбрать при составлении таблицы MySQL, для того чтобы можно было сохранять в нее изображения?

Comment: BLOB. Но я бы этого не делал, обычно изображениям в БД не место

Comment: Сохранить изображение файлом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для бинарных банных в mySQL есть тип "[binary large object (BLOB)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)" (большой бинарный объект). В нём и храните. Обратите внимание на максимальный [размер](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) данных в таких полях:

```
BLOB        L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16 (~64 Кб)
MEDIUMBLOB  L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24 (~16 Мб)
LONGBLOB    L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32 (~ 4 Гб)
```

Заранее прикиньте какого максимального размера будут файлы и заведите соответствующее поле.

Эти поля переменной длины и лучше вынести их в отдельную таблицу, а не хранить вместе с другими полями постоянной длины и с индексами по ним. Иначе изменение картинок в таблице будет накладным т.к. приведёт к перестроению индекса.